# How to download image only for mobile version of site?

Tags: html, css

In mobile version of my site i have another picture of main recipe, size = 70KB, and i wanna that image downloaded only for mobile version, how to do it? I made this solution, maybe someone has a better solution? 
scr 60B pixel for validation alt= hold alt + 255

https://satoriq.github.io/Lemon-Recipes/ -site for checking downloads

```
<picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 425px)"
          srcset="img/main-recipe-mobile.jpg">
        <img class="main-recipe__mobile" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt=" ">
</picture>
```

Comment: You can use srcset size attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using JavaScript I think the best solution is like this:

```
<style>
  .desktop {display: block;}
  .mobile {display: none;}
  @media (max-width: 425px) {
    .desktop {display: none;}
    .mobile {display: block;}
  }
</style>
<figure>
  <figcaption>FIGURE CAPTION TEXT</figcaption>
  <img class="desktop" src="desktop.jpg" alt="alternative text for desktop" />
  <img class="mobile" src="mobile.jpg" alt="alternative text for mobile" />
</figure>
```

P.S:
I changed the picture tag into figure in order to add the recommended figcaption. You can change it back to picture if you prefer.

Good Luck and you can read more about Media Queries here: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/